# http header not found in containerResponseContext

Tags: http, jersey, http-headers

I set an http responseheader "APP-ID" in my rest api by injecting HttpServletResponse. I have a container response filter that looks at the outgoing response. In that response, I do not see the "APP-ID" header!
However, my postman client shows the response header. Any idea why that is the case? How do I access the "APP-ID" header?

Comment: HttpServletResponse and ContainerResponseContext have no connection whatsoever

Comment: how do I print or log response headers that I set in a jersey filter? Is there no way to do that?

Comment: Just set them on the response. e.g `return Response.ok(body).header("API-ID", value).build()`

Comment: I am returning a json response,  injecting the httpservletResponse and setting the headers there.. I see the header in the postman response. Is there no way for me to print the http response in my code?

Comment: The point is why do you need to set the headers in the `HttpServletResponse`? Use the `Response` to set the headers. If you set the headers like in my example, you can get them in the ContainerResponseContex

Comment: My rest api method returns a custom object with error codes built in, and not Response.ok(body).header("API-ID", value).build()... I do not want to change the signature there..

Comment: And that's one of the bad things about not returning `Response`. You are limited in what you can do. I personally _always_ return `Response`. Not sure what you can do then, except use a servlet filter, if you really want to stick with HttpServletResponse. Personally I think it's tacky.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to "get" the header from HttpServletResponse ? I am able to set it, but dont see a way to "get" it

Comment: Have you tried to just inject the HttpServletResponse into the ContainerResponseFilter?

Comment: yes, tried that. but httpservletresponse only has "setHeader" methods, not get header. And the containerResponseContext does not seem to have my header

Comment: What about `getHeaderNames()`. Iterate that and use it to `getHeader(String)`. I just tested right now, and it works fine

Comment: Strange, i dont have the getter.. looks like Im using an old jar that needs to be updated. will do that. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ContainerResponse.

```
public class CustomFilter implements ResourceFilter, ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter, javax.servlet.Filter {

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
        response.getHttpHeaders().add("APP-ID", "whatever ");
        return response;
    }
}
```